# How to edit the text in eps files?

Tags: text, eps

I have to modify only the text of an EPS file. I would like to do that without using programs such as inkscape, and I would rather modify the eps file opening it as a text file (for instance using gedit). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried editing it with gedit? eps are simply postscript files.

Comment: @Rinzwind yes but when I open it I cannot find the text that I see in the figure

Comment: Aha. Then your text is not a text but part of an image.  You might need a hex editor to find it :)

Comment: My image is an EPS file produced by Matlab. I could find the y label text (it was the same in the EPS file opened with gedit) but not the legend text